# How I can get the id and splice selected data? I used quasar framework

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

I have a code like this:

```
async showStore(){
      try{
        await this.$refs.mdStore.show();
        let data  = await this.$axios.get(`link`);
        this.mdStores.result = data.data.stores;          
        if(this.mdStores.result.length){
          console.log(this.mdStores.result.length);
          for(const [i,v] of this.mdStores.result.entries()){
            const idx = result.findIndex(row => row.id_store === v.id_store);
            if(idx !== -1){
              result.splice(idx, 1);
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

`const idx = result.findIndex(row => row.id_store === v.id_store);`
this code doesn't work and I always get error in this part.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: what is variable `result`? it's not declared anywhere in your code - it must be an Array

Comment: Also, splicing an Array in a loop that is going forward (0 ... length) is never a going to end well - you may want to either loop from end to beginning, or re-think your code completely

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: result is not defined
    at _loop (Lottery.edit.vue?8b73:293)
    at VueComponent._callee3$ (Lottery.edit.vue?8b73:316)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:62)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:288)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:114)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?c973:5)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?c973:27)

Comment: After the `this.mdStores.result = data.data.stores;` line, add `var result = this.mdStores.result;`.  The issue is that you have no variable called `result`, and that's what the error message is telling you.  That will fix your problem.  As the other comments suggested, you may encounter other issues after that.  But one step at a time.

Comment: Please add the data in `this.mdStores.result` here.

Comment: I have some data in datatable, how I can make sure that the item selected match with the id? I use selection="multiple" in my datatable. @Rijosh